# Handling "effectively" duplicate commands in CQRS

Tags: cqrs

We have some code similar to this:

```
public class Vehicle : Entity<int>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public async Task UpdatePassengers(UpdatePassengersCommand command, IValidatorProvider commandValidator, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await commandValidator.ValidateAndThrowAsync(command, cancellationToken);
    
        var domainEvent = new PassengersUpdatedEvent
        {
            VehicleId = Id,
            PrecintId = PrecintId,
            Passengers = new List<Passenger>(command.Passengers),
        };
    
        ApplyAndRaise(domainEvent);
    }
}
```

Commands are validated and rejected if they are malformed. Otherwise the event is created and applied. The problem is that the front-end (which we don't control) has bugs that causes it to send events that are effectively duplicates. In other words, it may send passengers Alice and Bob, and then shortly after it may send Bob and Alice. As far as the business is concerned the passengers are still the same, so no update needs to be applied.

How and where should this check be performed? In the UpdatePassengers method itself? If here, should it be wrapped in another validator that is passed into the method (perhaps a validator that validates the command against the aggregate)? Or should the Vehicle entity itself contain this type of logic?

Or are there better ways of doing this that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern is that your domain entity will contain state, which acts as a sort of memory of what has happened before; commands are then processed within the context of what has happened already.  In other words, think "state machine".

One of the things that a method like `ApplyAndRaise` will normally do is modify the state of the entity.  So the trick is to have that code update the entity in a way that allows you to detect is duplicate work, so that you can skip it

Your example here suggests that there is a passenger list somewhere, so the code might be made to look like:

```
public async Task UpdatePassengers(UpdatePassengersCommand command, IValidatorProvider commandValidator, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await commandValidator.ValidateAndThrowAsync(command, cancellationToken);

    if (! this.passengerList.equals(command.Passengers)) {
    
        var domainEvent = new PassengersUpdatedEvent
        {
            VehicleId = Id,
            PrecintId = PrecintId,
            Passengers = new List<Passenger>(command.Passengers),
        };
    
        ApplyAndRaise(domainEvent);
    }
}
```

In 2010, Marc de Graauw suggested that [nobody needs reliable messaging](https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging/), for this reason: that your domain logic should be smart enough to detect redundant changes.